# How can I iterate on columns of a table and update them with values of a list?

Tags: python, mysql

I have created two lists with the same length. One of them is a list of attributes(columns) and the other is a list of values.
I need to update each column with its corresponding value.

I have created a loop to update them one by one.

```
for i in range(1, len(attribute_column)):
    mycursor.execute( """UPDATE products SET %s=%s WHERE products.product_id = %d """ %(attribute_column[i],attribute_value[i],get_id))
```

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE products

Comment: you can't use the column name as   a param  .. for this you need  dinamic sql  .. not parameter binding ..

Comment: @scaisEdge How can I do that?

Comment: I have used a column name as a parameter on INSERT and it works.

Comment: This is SQL normally don't happen ..

Comment: Can you give me a hint?

Comment: .. just the time for write the code  ..  please

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it without "TABLE"?

So that is:

```
"""UPDATE products SET %s=%s WHERE products.product_id = %d"""
```

That should work i believe.

Comment: I'm afraid.It did not.

Comment: You are right . That was wrong. But the error is still the same.

Comment: BTW, you do know you can update mulitple columns in one query?? Why do you want to loop through columns??

Comment: Because it did not work either. The problem is with passing column titles. not with the loop.

Comment: If i use TABLE on my database it always gives an error. So even if it doesnt fix it, i would advise to remove that.

Comment: What is the content of the variable with the column name??

Comment: Both are lists of strings. The attribute_value[0] is an integer. but it has nothing to do with this update.

Comment: Im looking at your error, and if you remove TABLE it must change because TABLE is in the error. Im sorry for being so insistent but TABLE is not valid i believe. For example if i do "SELECT * FROM TABLE products" it gives the exact same error.

Comment: In that case, can you edit the question with the new code and error?

Comment: You changed the code, thank you. But what is the new error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

the use of var in SQL code is dangerous but it is necessary to create sql dynamically

```
sql = "UPDATE TABLE products SET " + attribute_column[i] +
         "=%s WHERE products.product_id = %s ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

```
 for i in range(1, len(attribute_column)):
            column = attribute_column[i]
            mycursor.execute( "UPDATE products SET " + attribute_column[i] + " = " +attribute_value[i]+ " WHERE products.product_id = %d" %(get_id) )
```